# Complex Javascript Object Parsing

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I have an xml as a javascript object. The xml looks like:

```
<map-Map>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="responseMessage"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="success"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="lastName"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="Page"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="phone"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="860-634-1602"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="fax"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="860-429-5183"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="email"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="larry.page@gmail.com"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="name"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="Alphabets Inc."></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="altPhone"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="860-429-0021"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="billingAddress"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <map-HashMap>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="postalCode"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="94043"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="addr1"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="addr2"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="Mountain View"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="state"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="California"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="country"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="Unites States"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                    <map-Entry>
                        <map-Key>
                            <std-String value="city"></std-String>
                        </map-Key>
                        <map-Value>
                            <std-String value="California"></std-String>
                        </map-Value>
                    </map-Entry>
                </map-HashMap>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="dummyList"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <col-LinkedList>
                    <std-String value="a"></std-String>
                    <std-String value="b"></std-String>
                    <std-String value="c"></std-String>
                </col-LinkedList>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="firstName"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="Larry"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="companyName"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="Google"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="contact"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="sundar.pichai@gmail.com"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
    </map-Map>
```

And I have a javascript object for this which looks like:

```
{
             'map-Map':{
                 'map-Entry':{
                     'map-Key':{
                       'std-String':{attributes:{value:'firstName'}}
                       },
                     'map-Value':{
                        'std-String':{attributes:{value:'Larry'}}
                       }
                 }
  }
};
```

What i want is to convert this into simple key value pairs such as:

```
{'responseMessage':'success', 'lastName':'Page', 'billingAddress':{'postalCode':'321021','addr1':'Mountain View'},'firstName':'Larry'}
```

Please help me with the logic to parse and create something like this and it will be good if it is generic as the nesting of nodes can be there. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I am trying to use recursion although I am newbie but this is going into an infinite loop:

```
function processedResult(map){
    var resultMap   =   {};
    var mapEntry = map['map-Entry'];
   for(x=0; x<mapEntry.length; x++){
    var value = '';
    var child = mapEntry[x];
    var key = child['map-Key']['std-String']['attributes']['value'];
    var valueNode = child['map-Value'];
    if(Object.keys(valueNode)[0] == 'std-String'){
        value = valueNode['std-String']['attributes']['value'];
    }else if(Object.keys(valueNode)[0] == 'map-HashMap'){
        value = processedResult(valueNode['map-HashMap']);
    }
       resultMap[key] = value;
   }
    return resultMap;
}
```

Adding the whole JS object:

```
{"map-Entry":[{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"responseMessage"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"success"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"lastName"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Page"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"phone"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"860-634-1602"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"fax"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"860-429-5183"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"email"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"larry.page@gmail.com"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"name"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Alphabets Inc."}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"altPhone"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"860-429-0021"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"billingAddress"}}},"map-Value":{"map-HashMap":{"map-Entry":[{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"postalCode"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"94043"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"addr1"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"addr2"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Mountain View"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"state"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"California"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"country"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Unites States"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"city"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"California"}}}}]}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"dummyList"}}},"map-Value":{"col-LinkedList":{"std-String":[{"attributes":{"value":"a"}},{"attributes":{"value":"b"}},{"attributes":{"value":"c"}}]}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"firstName"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Larry"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"companyName"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"Google"}}}},{"map-Key":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"contact"}}},"map-Value":{"std-String":{"attributes":{"value":"sundar.pichai@gmail.com"}}}}]}
```

I am stuck in an infinite loop when feeding the JS object to this:

```
var parse = function (node, obj) {
    //console.dir(node);
    var hashMap;
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "map-Map" ) {
        console.log('inside map-Map');
        parse(node["map-Map"],obj);
        return obj;
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "map-HashMap" ) {
        console.log('inside map-HashMap');
        //console.log(node);
        hashMap = {};
       _.each(node, function (node) {
            console.log(node);
            parse(node, hashMap);
        });
        //parse(node["map-HashMap"]["map-Entry"], hashMap);
        return hashMap;
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "col-LinkedList" ) {
        console.log('inside col-LinkedList');
        return _.reduce(node, function (linkedList, node) {
            linkedList.push(parse(node, {}));
            return linkedList;
        }, []);
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "map-Entry" ) {
        console.log('inside map-Entry');
        console.log(node["map-Entry"]);
        for(a=0; a<node["map-Entry"].length; a++){
            obj[parse(node["map-Entry"][a]["map-Key"], obj)] = parse(node["map-Entry"][a]["map-Value"], obj);
        }
        //obj[parse(node["map-Key"], obj)] = parse(node["map-Value"], obj);
        return obj;
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "map-Key" ) {
         console.log('inside map-Key');
        return parse(node["map-Key"][0], obj);
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "map-Value" ) {
        console.log('inside map-Value');
        return parse(node["map-Value"][0], obj);
    }
    // ..
    if ( Object.keys(node)[0] === "std-String" ) {
        console.log('inside std-String');
        return node["std-String"]["attributes"]["value"];
    }
};
```

Comment: could you provide whole JS object for the source XML

Comment: @RadekMichna Thanks for responding.. I have added the whole JS object in my question itself..I am sorry as it is not properly formatted.

Comment: ok, thx. see my answer

Comment: @RadekMichna Hi, just one question, does node.children denote the immediate children of that node? can you explain with any example.

Comment: here you can check the whole API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element . For ex.: <map-Entry> has two children: <map-Key> and <map-Value>. I'm printing out the node to the console with 'dir' func. If you click on any node in the console log, you can see its whole structure...

Comment: @RadekMichna See my edit. I am trying to apply the xml logic to the JS parsed object but m stuck in an infinite loop while feeding the JS object to this parse method. If you can tell me where am I doing wrong. I am sorry to be a noob.

Comment: The converted object does not match the source xml.. See 'map-Entry' should be simple object with two properties: 'map-Key' and 'map-Value'  but it is array in the whole JS you provided.. put console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments)) at beginning of the function to see what objects goes in each call, you should be able to figure out how to rewrite the function with some effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var parse = function (node, obj) {
    console.dir(node);
    var hashMap;
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "map-Map" ) {
        _.each(node.children, function (node) {
            parse(node, obj);
        });
        return obj;
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "map-HashMap" ) {
        hashMap = {};
        _.each(node.children, function (node) {
            parse(node, hashMap);
        });
        return hashMap;
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "col-LinkedList" ) {
        return _.reduce(node.children, function (linkedList, node) {
            linkedList.push(parse(node, {}));
            return linkedList;
        }, []);
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "map-Entry" ) {
        obj[parse(node.children[0], obj)] = parse(node.children[1], obj);
        return obj;
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "map-Key" ) {
        return parse(node.children[0], obj);
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "map-Value" ) {
        return parse(node.children[0], obj);
    }
    // ..
    if ( node.tagName === "std-String" ) {
        return node.getAttribute("value");
    }
};

var str = '<map-Map><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="responseMessage"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="success"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="lastName"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Page"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="phone"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="860-634-1602"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="fax"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="860-429-5183"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="email"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="larry.page@gmail.com"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="name"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Alphabets Inc."></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="altPhone"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="860-429-0021"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="billingAddress"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><map-HashMap><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="postalCode"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="94043"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="addr1"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="addr2"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Mountain View"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="state"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="California"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="country"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Unites States"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="city"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="California"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry></map-HashMap></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="dummyList"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><col-LinkedList><std-String value="a"></std-String><std-String value="b"></std-String><std-String value="c"></std-String></col-LinkedList></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="firstName"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Larry"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="companyName"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="Google"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry><map-Entry><map-Key><std-String value="contact"></std-String></map-Key><map-Value><std-String value="sundar.pichai@gmail.com"></std-String></map-Value></map-Entry></map-Map>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");    
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(xml.children[0], {}), null, 4));
```

I'm working with xml document and it's nodes but the principle should be the same with parsed JS obj.. Try to go through it and let me know if it is understanable.

Not sure if it's cross-brwser, should work in chrome.

See http://devdocs.io/lodash/ for _.each and _.reduce expl.

Comment: Perfect!...Its working just fine on chrome as well..Thanks alot!